# ¿Es posible enviar una variable php de forma automatica al cumplir una condicion?

Tags: php

¡Hola!, quisiera saber si es posible enviar  una variable de forma automatica al cumplirse una condicion if por ejemplo , enviar esta variable a otra página básicamente de forma muy simple es asi :

```php
    if(true){
    //Envio de variable
    }
```

Me ayudarían Muchisimo!.. Cualquier duda es un placer responder!!

Comment: Vos queres enviar un dato (informacion) de donde a donde???

Comment: a donde la quieres enviar, a la DB, a un formulario, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: @gbianchi Gracias por comentar! , enviarlo a otra pagina basicamente por ejemplo a delete.php , tal vez con un echo haciendo dentro del echo un form y enviarlo por ahi, es que resulta que quiero enviar esto dentro de condicionales por lo cual es dentro de etiqueta php

Comment: @JefferzonBol Gracias por comentar! , Quiero enviarlo a otra pagina por ejemplo a delete.php!

Comment: vos queres enviarlo dentro de un php en el servidor, a otro php en el servidor.. o sea, todo dentro de tu back.. capaz alguien te puede ayudar, si justamente explicas eso.. y no, no vas a mandar una variable, vas a mandar informacion...

Comment: @LuisCifuentes Dos cosas: 1) Cuando dices "enviar" te refieres a abrir una pagina nueva que apunte a ese script delete.php?  Entonces lo puedes hacer con un header(location) y usando parámetros GET en la url que le pongas dentro, o 2) Si te refieres a hacer algo en otro script y luego continuar con el mismo que estas ahora entonces puedes usar `include('delete.php')` o `require('delete.php')` (o sus sucedaneos `_once`) y ejecutar las funciones que ellos tengan usando las variables que ya tienes resueltas en el script.

Comment: @masterguru Gracias masterguru!!!